# 'node --version' returning Invalid argument on SunOS

Tags: node.js

'node --version' returning 'Invalid argument' on SunOS

I had just extracted the .tar.gz of the nodejs downloads under my home on SunOS

```
% /home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86/bin/node --version
/home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86/bin/node: Invalid argument
% /home/net/user1/node-v10.15.3-sunos-x64/bin/node --version
/home/net/user1/node-v10.15.3-sunos-x64/bin/node: Invalid argument
% isainfo -v
64-bit sparcv9 applications
        vis2 vis
32-bit sparc applications
        vis2 vis v8plus div32 mul32
% uname -a
SunOS server01 5.10 Generic_144500-19 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V440
%
```

As a non sudo user, I don't want to install nodejs globally on my system but extract and use it as a portable

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following env variables exported?

```
export NODEJS_HOME=/home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86/
export PATH=$PATH:$NODEJS_HOME/bin
```

if not you must set them or it just won't have the paths to call itself internally...

Comment: I don't have access to export command, but this is how I managed env variables
`code`
~/.cshrc
setenv NODEJS_HOME /home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86
set path=($path $NODEJS_HOME/bin)

% env
USER=user1
HOME=/home/net/user1
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86/bin
SHELL=/bin/csh
PWD=/home/net/user1
NODEJS_HOME=/home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86
% node --version
/home/net/user1/node-v8.1.4-sunos-x86/bin/node: Invalid argument
%
`code`